# Test if date occurs in multiple date ranges with R

Tags: r, date, intervals, date-arithmetic

I have a data frame with multiple date ranges (45 to be exact):

```
Range  Start       End
1      2014-01-01  2014-02-30
2      2015-01-10  2015-03-30
3      2016-04-20  2016-10-12
...    ...         ...
```

*They will never overlap*

I also have a data frame with various event dates (200K+):

```
Event  Date
1      2014-01-02
2      2014-03-20
3      2015-04-01
4      2016-08-18
...    ...
```

I want to test if these dates fall within any of these ranges:

```
Event  Date        InRange
1      2014-01-02  TRUE
2      2014-03-20  FALSE
3      2015-04-01  FALSE
4      2016-08-18  TRUE
...
```

What is the best way to perform this test? I have looked at lubridate's **between** and **interval** functions as well as various Stackoverflow questions, but cannot find a good solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a vector of your date range from the first data frame, then use `%in%` operator to check if each date of your events is in this date range. Assuming your first data frame is `dateRange`, and second `events`, putting the above logic in one line would be:

```
events$InRange <- events$Date %in% unlist(Map(`:`, dateRange$Start, dateRange$End))

events
  Event       Date InRange
1     1 2014-01-02    TRUE
2     2 2014-03-20   FALSE
3     3 2015-04-01   FALSE
4     4 2016-08-18    TRUE
```

Where we used the `Map` to create the date range vector. `Map` combined with `:` operator create a list of date range from the `Start` to the `End`. Somewhere close to `list(2014-01-01 : 2014-02-30, 2015-01-10 : 2015-03-30, 2016-04-20 : 2016-10-12 ...)`(symbolically, not valid), with the `unlist`, we flatten it as a vector of date range which could then be used with `%in%` conveniently.

Comment: Awesome one liner - Works a charm!!! Can you explain the unlist and Map part please?

Comment: Just updated the explanation. If it is still not clear, check the output of `Map(`:`, c(1,2), c(3,4))` and you will see how it works.

Answer (score 4):

Having ordered, non-overlapping intervals in your first "data.frame", you could test -for each event date- if it is above a `$Start` and its respective `$End`. Using `findInterval` to reduce relational comparisons and memory needed.

```
findInterval(events$Date, ranges$Start) > findInterval(events$Date, ranges$End)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

With data (modified "2014-02-30"):

```
ranges = structure(list(Range = 1:3, Start = structure(c(16071, 16445, 
16911), class = "Date"), End = structure(c(16129, 16524, 17086
), class = "Date")), .Names = c("Range", "Start", "End"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")

events = structure(list(Event = 1:4, Date = structure(c(16072, 16149, 
16526, 17031), class = "Date")), .Names = c("Event", "Date"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

Write your own `function` to check if a list of dates are in any of a number of intervals.

```
date.in <- function(x){
m <- NULL
for (i in 1:NROW(df)){m <- c(m,  ifelse(x>=df[i,1] & x<=df[i,2], TRUE, FALSE))}
any(m)}
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(start=c("2014-01-01", "2015-01-10", "2016-04-20"), 
       end=c("2014-02-30", "2015-03-30", "2016-10-12"))
df[] <- lapply(df, as.character)

s <- c("2014-01-02", "2014-03-20", "2015-04-01", "2016-08-18")
```

Test using string `s`.

```
as.character(lapply(s, date.in))#TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE
```